# How to pipe commands in testcontainers execInContainer metod

Tags: java, bash, redis, testcontainers

I would like to run piped commands on docker through testcontainer `execInContainer` method. I'm able to run a single command (e.g. `execInContainer("redis-cli",  "keys", "*")`, but when providing a pipe (e.g. `execInContainer("redis-cli",  "keys", "*", "|", "grep", "-v", "test")`) it reads it as it belongs to the previous command (`ERR wrong number of arguments for 'keys' command`). What I want to achieve is to remove all keys from redis, beside one. The full script is as follow `redis-cli keys * | grep -v test | xargs redis-cli DEL`. Any idea how could I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I raised [this issue](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/4612#issuecomment-955590270) with the testcontainers team.

It looks like you can do:

```
execInContainer("sh", "-c", "foo | bar")
```

Can you please try this? It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note (for future myself :-) ), one can use redirection, pipe and other bash features in this manner.

```java
execInContainer("sh", "-c", "echo 'foo;' > bar");
```